# C program to replace a word in a text by another given word

Tags: c

I need help with an exercise in C. This is what I tried to do, but it doesn't work.

```
int main()
{
    int i, leng;
    char phrase[DIM], word[DIM], word2[DIM];

    printf("Write a sentence\n>>");
    fgets(phrase, sizeof(phrase), stdin);

    printf("Enter the word you want to replace in the sentence\n>> ");
    fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);

    printf("What do you want to replace it with?\n>> ");
    fgets(word2, sizeof(word2), stdin);

    leng = strlen(phrase);

    for (i = 0; i < leng; i++) {
        if (phrase[i] == word) {
            phrase[i] = word2;
        }
    }
    printf("%s", phrase);
    ...
```

When I start it, these warnings appear:

> assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without
> a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>
> comparison between pointer and integer

Comment: you cannot compare arrays like this `if(frase[i] == parola){`, need to use [`strcmp`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html)

Comment: You're also not looking for individual words within frase, nor are you making any length adjustment to fraze when you try to substitute in parola2 (which might not be the same length as parola)

Comment: @IrAM can you do an example with my code?

Comment: @Rup thanks, i fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Since I think you want to change only a letter it's easier to not create a string for parola and parola2. (The space before the %c it's to "eat" the enter or it will jump that question.)

```
    int i, leng;
    char frase[100], parola, parola2;

    printf("Inserisci una frase\n>>");
    gets(frase);

    printf("Inserisci la lettera che vuoi sostituire della frase\n>> ");
    scanf("%c", &parola);

    printf("Con cosa vuoi sostituirla?\n>> ");
    scanf(" %c", &parola2);
    
    leng = strlen(frase);
    
    
    for(i=0;i<leng;i++){
        if(frase[i] == parola){
            frase[i] = parola2;
        }
    }
    
    printf("%s", frase);
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I apologize by saying that I don't understand what you mean; plus the program doesn't work.

Comment: This only substitutes single letters not words (but I think that's what "la lettera" means, letter not word?) but this does work for me.

Comment: @Rup sorry, with "lettera" i want to mean the word.. i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You said this was an exercise, so here are instructions rather than a complete solution.

Our options are:

1. replace the word in-place in phrase - this is do-able, but given we don't know for sure that word and word2 are the same length this is going to be slightly tricky, so let's pick another way
2. make a new character array for the output string and assemble the string with replacements in this new array
3. print the various parts of the output string as we go, and don't assemble them into a buffer.

In all cases what we want to do is to work through phrase

- find the next instance of word in phrase
- if there is one

  - copy / print everything from the last position up to the start of the word we've found
  - copy / print word2
  - advance our cursor past the end of the found word and start again
- if there are no more instances of word

  - copy / print the rest of the string

The specific C string operations you need are

- [strstr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) - find the first instance of one string in another; returns the start of the found string, or null if not found
- [strcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) - copy a whole string to another place
- [strncpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) - copy a given number of characters from one string to another

Let's consider the output buffer method, #2. To do that, you'll need to:

- declare a new output buffer, e.g. `char buffer[DIM]`.
- declare input and output buffer cursors. It'll be easier to work with char* cursors, e.g. `char* input = phrase; char* output = buffer;`
- loop

  - find the next instance of `word` starting at `input` using `strstr`, e.g. `char* next_word = strstr(input, word);`
  - if `next_word != null`

    - copy everything from `input` to `next_word` to `output`, and advance `output` to the end of the characters you've just copied
    - copy `word2` to `output`, and advance `output` past the end of `word2` that you've just copied
    - advance `input` to `next_word` plus the length of `word`
  - else (i.e. `next_word == null`)

    - copy everything after `input` to the end of `phrase` to `output`
- print `output` as before.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for keeping answering. Anyway, really can't understand, I am a beginner; Can I have a simple code example?

Comment: `strncpy`: just say no... https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

Comment: @chqrlie Where you'd use strncpy here you're definitely appending another string after it, so that doesn't apply.

Comment: But I had meant to mention buffer overflows: if you were doing this properly you'd need to check that you don't overflow the output buffer whenever you're writing to it.

Comment: Advising a C beginner programmer to use `strncpy` is downright evil, because this function does not do what they will expect.  To copy a given number of characters from a string to another, just use `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 0):

This exercise is somewhat tricky because the resulting string may be much longer than the original one. Here are steps to achieve it:

- get the original string in `frase`. `fgets()` is fine for this but remove the trailing newline.
- get the word to replace `parola`.
- get replacement word `parola2`.
- in a loop: search and count the number of occurrences of `parola` in `frase` using `strstr()`.
- allocate an array of size `strlen(frase) + count * strlen(parola2) - count * strlen(parola) + 1` with `char *result = malloc(size)`.
- in a second loop, starting at `char *p = frase, *r = result;`.

  - search for the next occurrence of `parola` with `q = strstr(p, parola)`
  - if found, append the character from `p` to `q` to the result using `memcpy(r, p, q - p)`, then append `parola2`, update `p` to `q + strlen(parola)`, `r` to `r + (q - p) + strlen(parola2)` and iterate
  - if not found, append the rest of the phrase to the result with `strcpy()`.
- return the result. the caller will be responsible for discarding this array with `free(result)`.
- there is one special to handle carfully: if `parola` is an empty string.

Here is a simple implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strreplace(const char *s, const char *w1, const char *w2) {
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    size_t len1 = strlen(w1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(w2);
    size_t size = len + 1;
    const char *p, *q;
    char *result, *r;

    if (len >= len1 && len1 != len2 && len1 != 0) {
        // count the number of occurrences of w1 in s
        for (p = s; (p = strstr(p, w1)) != NULL; p += len1)
            size = size + len2 - len1;
    }
    r = result = malloc(size);
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (len1 != 0) {  /* don't replace the empty string */
        for (p = s; (q = strstr(p, w1)) != NULL; p = q + len1) {
            memcpy(r, p, q - p);
            r += q - p;
            memcpy(r, w2, len2);
            r += len2;
        }
    }
    strcpy(r, p);
    return result;
}

#define DIM 100

int main() {
    char phrase[DIM], word[DIM], word2[DIM];
    char *result;

    printf("Write a sentence\n>> ");
    if (!fgets(phrase, sizeof(phrase), stdin))
        return 1;
    phrase[strcspn(phrase, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the newline if any

    printf("Enter the word you want to replace in the sentence\n>> ");
    if (!fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin))
        return 1;
    word[strcspn(word, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the newline if any

    printf("What do you want to replace it with?\n>> ");
    if (!fgets(word2, sizeof(word2), stdin))
        return 1;
    word2[strcspn(word2, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the newline if any

    result = strreplace(phrase, word, word2);
    if (result == NULL) {
        printf("memory allocation failure\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%s\n", result);
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
>> Sarah e bellissima
Enter the word you want to replace in the sentence
>> e
What do you want to replace it with?
>> erava
Sarah erava beravallissima
```

If you want to only replace exact words, you must specify what a *word* is. You could use the same function as above but replace `strstr` with a function that locates a *word* inside a string such as this one:

```
char *findword(const char *s, const char *w) {
    size_t len = strlen(w);
    char *p;
    while ((p = strstr(s, w)) != NULL) {
        if ((p == s || p[-1] == ' ') && (p[len] == '\0' || p[len] == ' '))
            break;
        s = p + len;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your need to treat `word` and `word2` as char arrays.

```
        if (phrase[i] == word) {
            phrase[i] = word2;
        }
```

In this block `phrase[i]` has `char` type and `word`/`word2` are `char[]`. Presumably, you want to test that the next `strlen(word)` characters at `phrase[i]` all match `word` (e.g. `phrase[i + j] == word[j]`). Similarly in terms of replacement, you probably want to replace `strlen(word2)` characters. Note that you will need to be careful here if the lengths of `word` and `word2` are not the same; I will leave that to you but here's a hint: you may consider using new buffer (`char[]`) for the result.